# Antialiasing doesn't work for small text, when using Polygons with holes

Tags: graphics, text, polygons, antialiasing

I have a weird problem with antialiasing of small text and Polygons. If I use Polygon with holes `poly1->poly2`, Antialiasing doesn't work, although I used `Antialiasing->True`. See this example:

```
poly1 = {{0, 0}, {3, 3}, {6, 0}};
poly2 = {{2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}};
text = Column@Table[Style["FontSize: " <> ToString@i, i, Italic], {i, 2, 22, 2}];

Graphics[{Antialiasing -> True, Polygon[poly1 -> poly2], Red, Text[text, {6, 3}]}]
```

[image]

If I use two single Polygons, without using the hole option it suddenly works:

```
    Graphics[{Antialiasing -> True, Polygon[poly1], White, Polygon[poly2], Red, Text[text, {6, 3}]}]
```

[image]

I know, that the font antialiasing is system dependent, but why does it change if I use different polygon methods and how can I avoid it using the hole option?

I'm using Mathematica 12.1 on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: Wow, this is a cool bug. Have you reported it to Wolfram Support? I couldn't reproduce it on 13.0 on Linux, but I also have a very high-DPI screen and it could be hard for me to make out the distinctions.

Comment: Version 13.0. I get 2 identical pictures.

Comment: Maybe you can try go to : `Edit -> Appearance -> Graphics -> Highest Quality` and there  move the slider to the right max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Work around. Add `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` to `Polygon`

```
Graphics[{Antialiasing -> True, 
  Polygon[poly1 -> poly2] // BoundaryDiscretizeRegion, Red, 
  Text[text, {6, 3}]}]
```

Comment: Wow, this works. Thank you very much!